# Shift cells in a data frame to the right based on row values

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, data-manipulation, tibble

I'm working with a data frame that was created from multiple tab separated text files imported as tibbles that are joined together using `rbind` . The files all contain similar column names but some of the values are under the wrong column when imported due to comments that are added in the creation of these files. I'm attempting to shift the non-comment cell values to their adjacent right column. I cannot alter the original files in any way.

Initial Example Data Frames Code:

```
df1<-df<-data.frame(
  c1=c("A","B","C",1,1,1),
  c2=c(1,1,1,5,NA,5),
  c3=c(5,5,5,"C","C","C"),
  c4=c("C","C","C",NA,NA,NA)
)

df2<-data.frame(
  c1=c("A","B","F",2,2,2),
  c2=c(2,2,2,6,6,6),
  c3=c(6,6,6,"D","D","D"),
  c4=c("D","D","D",NA,NA,NA)
)
```

Initial Example Data Frames:

```
> df1
  c1 c2 c3   c4
1  A  1  5    C
2  B  1  5    C
3  C  1  5    C
4  1  5  C <NA>
5  1 NA  C <NA>
6  1  5  C <NA>
> df2
  c1 c2 c3   c4
1  A  2  6    D
2  B  2  6    D
3  F  2  6    D
4  2 NA  D <NA>
5  2  6  D <NA>
6  2  6  D <NA>
```

Compiled Data Frame Code:

```
df<-rbind(df1,df2)
```

Compiled Data Frame:

```
> df
   c1 c2 c3   c4
1   A  1  5    C
2   B  1  5    C
3   C  1  5    C
4   1  5  C <NA>
5   1 NA  C <NA>
6   1  5  C <NA>
7   A  2  6    D
8   B  2  6    D
9   F  2  6    D
10  2 NA  D <NA>
11  2  6  D <NA>
12  2  6  D <NA>
```

Desired Data Frame:

```
     c1 c2 c3 c4
1     A  1  5  C
2     B  1  5  C
3     C  1  5  C
4  <NA>  1  5  C
5  <NA>  1 NA  C
6  <NA>  1  5  C
7     A  2  6  D
8     B  2  6  D
9     D  2  6  D
10 <NA>  2 NA  D
11 <NA>  2  6  D
12 <NA>  2  6  D
```

The comments and the repeating lines on the first coumln that are to be shifted a not always the same length or the same values nor are they always numeric.

I've tried using an altered version of a similar question to shift my values. [Using R to shift values to the left of data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079789/using-r-to-shift-values-to-the-left-of-data-frame)

```
df[]<-t(apply(df, 1, function(x) c(x[is.na(x)], x[!is.na(x)])))
```

However this code uses all `NA` values and some columns contain `NA` values so this would only work when the final column is `NA` and not any of the other columns.

```
> df
     c1   c2 c3 c4
1     A    1  5  C
2     B    1  5  C
3     C    1  5  C
4  <NA>    1  5  C
5  <NA> <NA>  1  C
6  <NA>    1  5  C
7     A    2  6  D
8     B    2  6  D
9     F    2  6  D
10 <NA> <NA>  2  D
11 <NA>    2  6  D
12 <NA>    2  6  D
```

Is there a way for this code to only use the final column as a guide to shift the appropriate cells to the right?

Edit: typo on modified code from similar question `df1` changed to `df`.

Comment: Are your the values in `c1` in your real dataset letters and `c2` numbers?  If so, I could see filtering out the rows with `c1` as letters, renaming the columns, and then binding things back together.

Comment: Unfortunatly it varies. There are times when they're characters and others when they are numeric values. It's not the most consistent of systems that creates the original files.

Comment: If it varies in some pattern, even if not letters vs numbers, you may be able to think of a way to filter things using regular expressions.  Or maybe filter on the last column containing NA?  I think that'd do it for your example datasets. I'm also a bit curious on what the original files look like, mostly in case there is some way to address this in the importing step. :)

Comment: There isn’t a set pattern but some of the comments have recurring characters. I was able to adapt the `t(apply(` line to use `grepl`  instead of `is.na(x)` with multiple characters to search those out and arrange it that way. It needs a bit of work since you need to know what some of the comments are ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**: Here is the solution. It is cumbersome a bit, but it works. To preserve the initial order a good idea is to set an index as column and sort final df with it. Later on, you can revert column back to index by `column_to_rownames` or simply by droping it with `select(df, -c('index'))`. With this, I hope I answered the question.

```
df <- rbind(df1,df2)
df <- mutate_all(df, as.character)
df <- rownames_to_column(df, 'index')

df_ok <- filter(df, !is.na(c4))
df_na <- filter(df, is.na(c4))
df_fin <- df_na %>%
 select(c4, everything()) %>%
 rename(c1 = c4, c2 = c1, c3 = c2, c4 = c3) %>%
 rbind(df_ok)
df_fin <- df_fin %>%
 mutate(index = as.integer(index)) %>%
 arrange(index)
```

Comment: This gets the columns to have the values they need quite nicely. The one thing I tried to add to it was `%>% arrange(c2,c1)` to try and get the data frame to have the same order as the example. it does put the comments in `c1` at the top of their respective `c2` but `c1` is not in the same order the example is in. That addition puts the order as: `[1] "C" "A" "B" NA  NA  NA  "A" "B" "F" NA  NA  NA` . I'm unsure if the `.by_group` argument can help in this.

Comment: This works great. Thanks for your help. I added `select` at the end to remove the `index` but this works perfectly.